# Windows Authentication/Forms Authentication? How best to design the system?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, iis

Can you please suggest a suitable architecture design for the problem I am facing now:

**Target:**

Users connect to the website. Website prompts them for a user-name and password.
These users have their own account BUT NOT ON THE DOMAIN LEVEL.
Sql server on another server will then authenticate these users but I don't want to create a **domain level user group or users**.  Users will then view their website data and edit it in the database, if desired.

Situation:

1. Using IIS to host website on server A
2. Using SQL Server to deploy the databases.  Databases are hosted on server B.

I am planning to create local users on server A.
Then I will use Windows Authentication on the IIS to authenticate the users.
These users do not belong to server B.

My assumption:

I will create a windows user on the domain level.  This user will belong on server A and server B.  I will then use this user's credentials as the application pool identity and will add this user as a user in the DB.

**Will that strategy work?  Do you recommend a better strategy?**

Answer (score 0):

Windows Authentication is more suitalble for Intranet Web Applications.
If your's is a classic public website, it's a better design to implement a Form Authentication with a registration form, instead of create a window user by hand for each new user that request access...
To query the database you don't need to create a new user: it's simpler to grant prvileges to the default asp.net user (something like *IUSR* with the machine name attacched somewhere, depends on the version of IIS), just be sure both servers belong tho the same domain.